# Azure VM, not being able to redirect domain

Tags: redirect, azure

I have a domain which is www.avvakampus.com.tr and what I want to is to redirct this domain to my Azure VM. However so far no luck.

**What I have done so far?**

The domain provider has only allows nameservers in it's portal. So i give lisanegitim.cloudapp.net as my nameserver, which is the url of my azure cloud service.

as you can see it is already redirected to lisanegitim.cloduapp

http://www.dnsinspect.com/avvakampus.com.tr/1462713328

And I also had added the DNS records to my DNS manager:

[image]

However when I try to load or psping it is unable to be reached. I am very confused and lost. Please any suggestion might be helpful.

BTW, I was able to redirect another domain which is www.edumap.net by simply adding A records on it's panel. However, their domain providers are not the same and edumap's domain portal gives you the ability of adding IP addresses, A records and etc but www.avvakampus.com.tr do not.

Comment: Do you have inbound DNS allowed in the NSG for your VM?

Comment: Can you explain it more? What is NSG? How do I allow the DNS's?

Comment: @EgeAydın Are you able to reach your site via its `cloudapp.net` name?

Comment: yes and also with a custom domain: www.edumap.net

Comment: I've been able to successfully test your DNS by connecting and resolving all the domain names you mentioned and have in the screenshot to the IP: 13.80.13.211, the IP also works in a browser as well as the domain names. could you explain what is the problem you're trying to solve as I can't seems to find one.

Comment: Someone else solved the issue for me. Thanks anyway.